# Tensorflow error " ImportError: DLL loaad failed with error code-1073741795"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Issue in importing TENSORFLOW(error code-1073741795 in jupyter notebook, Pycharm, Anaconda command line and in spyder. Howevery I am able to install successfully. But when I'm trying import then I am getting this error
"ImportError: DLL load failed with error code-1073741795".

I have install all the versions of VS redistributable.

[image]
[image]

I am using win 7 with 64 bit os. I tried to install on tensorflow on all the versions of python 3.6, 3.7
& 3.8. with different versions of tensorflow. Did anyone encountered with error code-1073741795???

```
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code-1073741795

Failed to load the native tensorflow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

what does error code-1073741795 means?
How do we fix it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error like this when installing tensorflow. It was because tensorflow was not installed properly.

1. First, delete your current installed tensorflow completely.
2. Install Anaconda.
3. Make a new conda environment ([this will help](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)).
4. After creating a conda environment, activate it.
5. After activating, write: 'conda install tensorflow==1.15.0'

I am suggesting tensorflow 1.15.0 because I have found it more stable and better than any other version.

To test it is working properly, write:

```
    python
```

This will activate python, then write:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    print(tf.__version__)
```

You may get some warnings when importing tensorflow, but ignore the warnings, you will not get any errors. (if you get any error, comment)

Comment: WIth tensorflow 1.15.01. What should be my anaconda aur python version??

Comment: You should use latest version of anaconda and python 3.7 (I don't know if tensorflow 1.15.0 works with any python version, as i have not tried it)

Comment: Unfortunately After 50 hours of struggle  leads to same error message.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your windows, anaconda version, python version? Which windows are you using?

Comment: Performed the steps 5 times again and again...But still same error message 1073741795

OS: win 7. 
64bit
1) Uninstalled tensorflow, python, anaconda, pycharm.
2) Reinstall python 3.7 and the anaconda and pycharm and tensorflow1.15.0 (tried all other versions too).
3) Install  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (All Versions)
3) Then created new virtual environment and then activated. 
4) After that able to install tensorflow but 
5) Tried to import tensorflow. But unable to import. Gives same error 1073741795. 
Same error message in jupyter notebook, pycharm and in CLI.

Comment: Uninstalled tensorflow, python, anaconda, pycharm.   
Reinstall python 3.7 and the anaconda and pycharm and tensorflow1.15.0 (tried all other versions too).     
Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (All Versions)   
Then created new virtual environment and then activated.  
After that able to install tensorflow but  
Tried to import tensorflow. But unable to import. Gives same error 1073741795.   
Same error message in jupyter notebook, pycharm and in CLI.

Comment: sorry I didnt uninstall my base python3.7....other than base python3.7 i have uninstall and reinstall everything. Do you think i should uninstall my base python3.7 also? if yes then which version should i install again

Comment: @AnandGoel That base python 3.7 was created when you were making a new environment in anaconda, right?

Comment: @ Dhruv Agarwal. Yes that main base python3.7 was always there. On the top of it. I was uninstalling anaconda, pycharm and reinstalling. and installed python3.6 also. but didnt work.